# How do I initialize a two-dimensional array using Array.Empty()?

Tags: c#, arrays

Here's the code:

```
int[,] Arr;
Arr = Array.Empty();
```

And here's the compile error for the second line:

> Error CS0411  The type arguments for method 'Array.Empty()' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

This should be a simple syntax fix, but I haven't been able to get it.

Comment: `int[,] Arr = new int[0, 0];`.

Comment: Why do you want to use `Array.Empty`, and not `new int[0, 0]`?

Comment: This compiles:

int[][,] Arr2;
Arr2 = Array.Empty<int[,]>();

So, I'm expecting a simple syntactic answer.
I might be wrong to expect that, though.

Comment: @HalHeinrich That's _not_ a two-dimensional array. It's a jagged array (i.e., an array of arrays) where the _inner_ array is a two-dimensional array. The simple syntax is either `new [0, 0]` or creating your own custom method. There's nothing built-in for what you're trying to do. FYI, the way `Array.Empty()` method works for one-dimensional arrays under the hood is also by returning `new T[0]`. There's no magic here.

Comment: The documentation for the `Array.Empty` method states that it returns a 1D array. It should be obvious that it cannot do what you want. Pretty much all member of the `Array` class are for 1D arrays only.

Comment: *"I might be wrong to expect that"*. You are. That is creating a 1D array where the type of the elements is a 2D array. The code you showed doesn't create any 2D arrays. It just creates a 1D array where each element can be a 2D array. A factory that makes egg cartons doesn't produce any eggs.

Answer (score 5):

You may use:

```
int[,] Arr = new int[0, 0];
```

Or if you'd like to replicate the `Empty()` method for multidimensional arrays, you could write a helper class for that:

```
static class MultiDimArray
{
    public static T[,] Empty2D<T>() => new T[0, 0];

    public static T[,,] Empty3D<T>() => new T[0, 0, 0];

    // Etc.
}
```

**Usage:**

```
int[,] Arr = MultiDimArray.Empty2D<int>();
```

---

To take this a step further (and actually make it useful), we can make this work *exactly* like `Array.Empty()`, and thus avoid unnecessary memory allocation by using static readonly fields so that they're only initialized once:

```
static class MultiDimArray
{
    public static T[,] Empty2D<T>() => Empty2DArray<T>.Value;
    public static T[,,] Empty3D<T>() => Empty3DArray<T>.Value;
    // Etc.

    private class Empty2DArray<T> { public static readonly T[,] Value = new T[0, 0]; }
    private class Empty3DArray<T> { public static readonly T[,,] Value = new T[0, 0, 0]; }
    // Etc.
}
```

Comment: main advantage of `ArrayEmpty<T>()` method is that it reuses same object. Your variant creates new instances on each call.

Comment: @Pavel You probably didn't read the last paragraph and the following code block :)

Comment: Indeed, my bad =)